# Finding second derivative for $x=\sin t$ and $y= \sin 2t$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If $x=\sin t$ and $y= \sin 2t$, how to find second derivative of $y$ w.r.t $x$ ? Or rather how to prove $(1-x^{2})\frac{d^{2}y}{dx^{2}}-x\frac {dy}{dx}+4y=0$?

Is there any shortcuts to find these derivatives quickly ?

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{\frac{dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}} =\frac{2cos2t}{cost}$$

$$\dfrac{d^{2}y}{dx^2} = {\dfrac{d(\frac{dy}{dx})}{dt}}{\frac{dt}{dx}}$$
$$\dfrac{d^{2}y}{dx^2} =\frac{cost(-4sin2t) + 2co2tsint}{cos^{3}t}$$

Now substitute these in the differential equation and you will get the result.

Answer (score 1):

Eliminate $t$ in the beginning itself.

$ y^2 = 4 \sin^2 t \cos^2 t = 4 x^2 ( 1 - x^2), $

Successive derivatives can be plugged into the DE without parameter $t$,but only $x$,  now you can carry it further..

EDIT1:

The trick in this is, second derivative leads to a simplification, as :

$$ \ddot  y = - 4 t $$

due to which I withdraw my above earlier approach. Not because it is wrong, but because it opens up a quicker and more straight forward procedure given below compared to the BFI and, sorry if appeared misleading... I am sure you tried with due diligence.

Primes are differentiation with respect to x and dots with to time t as parameter.

$$ y^{'} = \dfrac{\dot y }{\dot x} \tag{1}$$

$$ \dfrac{d^{2}y}{d x^2}= \dfrac{\dot x  \ddot y - \dot y  \ddot x }{\dot x^3} \tag{2}$$

( got by differentiating (1) )

$$ = \dfrac{\dot x \cdot - 4 y -2 \cos 2t \cdot \sin t}{(\cos t) ^3} $$

$$ = \dfrac{ \cos t \cdot -4 \cdot 2 \cos t\sin t + 2 ( 2 (\cos  t)^2 -1) \sin t}{(\cos t) ^3} $$

$$ = \dfrac{ \sin t }{(\cos t)^3} ( - 4 (\cos t)^2 -2 ) $$

First Term:   take out $ T = \tan t $ as common factor;

$$ (1-x^2) y^{''} =  ( - 4 (\cos t)^2 -2 ) \tag {3} $$

Next, second term:

$$ - x y ^{'} = - \sin t \dfrac{2 ( 2 (\cos t)^2 -1) }{\cos t}  \tag{4}   $$

last term :

$$ 4 \,y = 8\,T \,(\cos t )^2 \tag{5} $$

Plug in the three terms, it tallies.

Incidentally this is the Lissajou's Figure of 8 with frequency ratio 2/1 and without phase difference.

Comment: Show me the next steps also...i'm not getting the solution.